# Cast TreeMap.Submap return: SortedMap, back to TreeMap

Tags: java, treemap, sortedmap

This seems too tricky for me to be doing this correctly.

I have a `TreeMap<Double, (user-defined)Object>`, of which I am taking a submap:

```
        public static reqObj assignObj(reqObj vArg, int startDate, int endDate){
                reqObj vOut=new reqObj();



                if (keyAt(vArg.requestObject,startDate)>-1 && keyAt(vArg.requestObject,endDate)>-1){
                    System.err.println(keyAt(vArg.requestObject,startDate));
                    System.err.println(keyAt(vArg.requestObject,endDate));

                    //vOut.requestObject=(TreeMap<Double, dayObj>)

                    vArg.requestObject.subMap(
                            keyAt(vArg.requestObject,startDate),
                            keyAt(vArg.requestObject,endDate));

                }

                return vOut;
        }
```

This works just as expected, but when I go to cast my sorted map back to `(TreeMap)` I get the following error:

```
  java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.TreeMap$SubMap
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is exactly what the error says: the returned submap is **not** a standard `TreeMap`, it is an instance of an implementation-defined inner class. If you look at the declaration of `subMap`:

```
public SortedMap subMap(Object fromKey, Object toKey)
```

all it guarantees is that the returned object implements the `SortedMap` interface, so that's the only thing you can safely cast to.

That being said, there is no reason to actually cast to a `TreeMap` because it doesn't provide any additional functionality over what a `SortedMap` does.

Comment: i guess the short answer is "No", while the longer answer is just make your code conscious of the fact that if it sends a TreeMap through a .submap it should be prepared to handle the return of a SortedMap?

Comment: @jason m: That's why it's always good to handle objects through interfaces, that way you don't need to worry whether it is really a `TreeMap` or some other class.

Comment: Would you mind recommending where I could read about what you are saying (re: handling objects through interfaces?) That would be great. Thanks!

Comment: @jason m: It's nothing too involved, but here's a very simple example: [Use interface references to Collections](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=26)